# Bitrix: how to create Google Sitemap automatically using agent?

Tags: sitemap, agent, bitrix

Bitrix 1C has an option: Google Sitemap.

How to create an agent, which will create this sitemap automatically? I mean, what I need to write, some function...

Answer (score 1):

1) create function that will be run by agent, for example 'agentSitemapGenerator',
in /bitrix/php_interface/init.php

```
function agentSitemapGenerator()
{

        // implement sitemap generation call

        // function must return its name
        return "agentSitemapGenerator();";
}
```

2) implement sitemap generation call in your function.
I found this example

```
//подключение модуля поиска
if(CModule::IncludeModule('search'))
{
   //В этом массиве будут передаваться данные "прогресса". Он же послужит индикатором окончания исполнения.
   $NS=Array();
   //Задаем максимальную длительность одной итерации равной "бесконечности".
   $sm_max_execution_time = 0;
   //Это максимальное количество ссылок обрабатываемых за один шаг.
   //Установка слишком большого значения приведет к значительным потерям производительности.
   $sm_record_limit = 5000;
   do {
      $cSiteMap = new CSiteMap;
      //Выполняем итерацию создания,
      $NS = $cSiteMap->Create("ru", array($sm_max_execution_time, $sm_record_limit), $NS);
      //Пока карта сайта не будет создана.
   } while(is_array($NS));
}
```

code from: http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/blogs/oracle/254.php

description of CSiteMap::Create in official documentation https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/search/classes/csitemap/create.php

3) create agent in control panel